# How can I SELECT each cell of a wide SQL table?

Tags: sql-server, select

Say I have a *wide* table in SQL with many (say over a hundred) fields. Is there a way to query for a record set showing each *cell* of that table?

To go from...

```
Foo Bar Fizz Buzz (etc)
1   XYZ 84   J
2   ABC 29   NULL
3   KLM 73   Y
```

To...

```
Foo Bar Field Value    
1   XYZ Fizz  84
1   XYZ Buzz  J  
2   ABC Fizz  29
3   KLM Fizz  73
3   KLM Buzz  Y
(etc)
```

Preferably without having to copy/paste a line 100 times, once for each field.

I accept if this were possible, that 'Value' field would have to contain non-string values converted to a string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you would want to use UNPIVOT.

However it is made a bit more complex as you have different types in the columns for Fizz, Buzz etc. The resultant column has to be of a single type so you would need to do a bit of casting

Assuming your table is named "MyTable" the code would be:

```
select
    unpvt.Foo,
    unpvt.Bar,
    unpvt.Field,
    unpvt.Value
from
(
    select
        Foo,
        Bar,
        CAST(Fizz as VARCHAR(3)) as Fizz,
        CAST(Buzz as VARCHAR(3)) as Buzz,
        ... <repeat for other columns>
        from
            Mytable
    ) as p unpivot(Value for Field in(
        Fizz,
        Buzz)) as unpvt
```

Where they have all been casted into the type of varchar(3) but this could be something else as long as it is consistent (and possible!)

Unfortunately you still need to manually add all the relevant columns into the Unpivot statement. If you want to do this without having to type all the columns out then you would need a Dynamic SQL solution. See this question for an idea of how to implement this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/passing-column-names-dynamically-to-unpivot

Answer (score 0):

Using `CROSS JOIN` you can also do the following.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (Foo INT, Bar VARCHAR(10), Fizz INT, Buzz VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Tbl        
VALUES  
(1, 'XYZ', 84, 'J'),
(2, 'ABC', 29, NULL),
(3, 'KLM', 73, 'Y')


SELECT 
    Foo,
    Bar,
    A.Field,
    CASE WHEN A.Field = 'Fizz' THEN CAST(T.Fizz AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE T.Buzz END Value
FROM 
    @Tbl T CROSS JOIN 
    (VALUES ('Fizz'), ('Buzz') ) A(Field)
```

Result:

```
Foo         Bar        Field Value
----------- ---------- ----- ----------
1           XYZ        Fizz  84
1           XYZ        Buzz  J
2           ABC        Fizz  29
2           ABC        Buzz  NULL
3           KLM        Fizz  73
3           KLM        Buzz  Y
```

You can add constraints for two columns to the WHERE condition if you do not want null values.